# PBI item save and close

Tags: azure-devops

When adding or editing a product backlog item (PBI), the description and acceptance criteria fields can be maximized to fill the entire dialog. But then the *Save and Close* button disappears.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to save and close? Or do I have to minimize the field first (at the top of the dialog), then use the close and save button (at the bottom of the dialog)?

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The solution I've found is to:

1. Press <kbd>escape</kbd> to minimise the field
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> to save the item
3. Press <kbd>escape</kbd> again to close the item

If the PBI has been modified and not saved (i.e. #2 above is skipped) then using <kbd>escape</kbd> to close the item will present a dialog advising that closing the item will lose any changes. The OK button is selected by default, so pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> will close the dialog and the PBI and any changes will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

There does not look to be a shortcut for this. Save is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> but no Save and Close.

Maybe you can request it on http://visualstudio.uservoice.com

Comment: Thanks, but that only works while the field is not maximised.

Comment: I would request it on uservoice.